# Rotation of object is off kilter despite keframing on z axis

Tags: keyframes

I've been trying to get the head of R2D2 to rotate properly, and despite rotating him with r+z+z he produces a slight off balance rotation as you can see here where his head sort of dips in when it rotates:

[image]

So I also tried a limit rotation constraint for his head but it produced really wonky results that couldn't be fixed with any kind of adjustments in the constraint modifier:

[image]

Finally I tried delta rotations but that just made things worse.  Is there any way I can make his head rotate properly without having to delete all my rotation keyframes?

Comment: Have you checked the curves in the graph editor?

Comment: @Haunt_House yep they're all linear...is there something else there that could be affecting the z axis?

Comment: when you say linear, I interpret it as straight lines. What you want is to have only a single axis have any ups or downs. the rest can be deleted. If the head rotates around the Z axis, X and Y should be dead.

Comment: Hm I tried deleting the x and y, but that just made him go wonky again :(

Comment: Have you parented the head to anything? That usually works because it puts animation into a local context. By the way, I have no idea around which axis you have animated the head. So I don't know whether x and y were the right ones. My guess is you have animated global rotation. The local z z just distributed it to 3 axes.

Comment: @Haunt_House it's parented to the body, which is a parent to his legs and other parts.  The whole robot is parented to a wireframe cube, which is what moves him along the path.  I thought that the z z command just rotated the z axis, but you're right it's been distributed to the 3 axes.  The orientation is set to local.